# spark - stack multiple when conditions from an Array of column expressions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have the below spark dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(("US",10),("IND",20),("NZ",30),("CAN",40)).toDF("a","b")
df.show(false)
+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|US |10 |
|IND|20 |
|NZ |30 |
|CAN|40 |
+---+---+
```

and I'm applying the `when()` condition as follows:

```
df.withColumn("x", when(col("a").isin(us_list:_*),"u").when(col("a").isin(i_list:_*),"i").when(col("a").isin(n_list:_*),"n").otherwise("-")).show(false)

+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |x  |
+---+---+---+
|US |10 |u  |
|IND|20 |i  |
|NZ |30 |n  |
|CAN|40 |-  |
+---+---+---+
```

Now to minimize the code, I'm trying the below:

```
val us_list = Array("U","US")
val i_list = Array("I","IND")
val n_list = Array("N","NZ")
val ar1 = Array((us_list,"u"),(i_list,"i"),(n_list,"n"))

val ap = ar1.map( x => when(col("a").isInCollection(x._1),x._2) )
```

This results in

```
ap: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = Array(CASE WHEN (a IN (U, US)) THEN u END, CASE WHEN (a IN (I, IND)) THEN i END, CASE WHEN (a IN (N, NZ)) THEN n END)
```

but when I try

```
val ap = ar1.map( x => when(col("a").isInCollection(x._1),x._2) ).reduce( (x,y) => x.y )
```

I get an error. How to fix this?

Comment: Why are you creating an array of values as us_list etc if you are not using it? you could have directly compare the 'a' column values and assigned a new value what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foldLeft on `ar1` list :

```
val x = ar1.foldLeft(lit("-")) { case (acc, (list, value)) =>
  when(col("a").isin(list: _*), value).otherwise(acc)
}

// x: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CASE WHEN (a IN (N, NZ)) THEN n ELSE CASE WHEN (a IN (I, IND)) THEN i ELSE CASE WHEN (a IN (U, US)) THEN u ELSE - END END END
```

Answer (score 1):

There is usually no need to combine `when` statements using `reduce`/`fold` etc. `coalesce` is enough because the `when` statements are evaluated in sequence, and gives `null` when the condition is false. Also it can save you from specifying `otherwise` because you can just append one more column to the list of arguments to `coalesce`.

```
val ar1 = Array((us_list,"u"),(i_list,"i"),(n_list,"n"))
val ap = ar1.map( x => when(col("a").isInCollection(x._1),x._2) )
val combined = coalesce(ap :+ lit("-"): _*)

df.withColumn("x", combined).show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  x|
+---+---+---+
| US| 10|  u|
|IND| 20|  i|
| NZ| 30|  n|
|CAN| 40|  -|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: yes, it's more of a style difference, but I just find it easier to construct a chain of when using coalesce rather than chaining them together with `.`/`reduce`